# How to use \nonumber in \gather environment?

Tags: equations, gather, equation-number

I have two equations in the `\gathered` environment.

```
\documentclass{book} 
  \usepackage{amsmath}
 
 \begin{document}  
 

\begin{equation} 
 \begin{gathered}
     \Delta U_{ab}+\Delta U_{ba}=0\\
    \int_{\vec r_a}^{\vec r_b}\vec F\cdot d\vec r +\int_{\vec r_b}^{\vec r_a}\vec F\cdot d\vec r=0
     \label{ce23}  

  \end{gathered} 
 \end{equation}
 
 \end{document}
```

Producing the output:

[image]

But instead, I want the following output using `\gathered` itself, instead of `\align` which I used for this MWE

[image]

Code for which is

```
   \documentclass{book} 
      \usepackage{amsmath}
     
     \begin{document}  
     

   
     \begin{align}
         \Delta U_{ab}&+\Delta U_{ba}=0 \nonumber\\
        \int_{\vec r_a}^{\vec r_b}\vec F\cdot d\vec r &+\int_{\vec r_b}^{\vec r_a}\vec F\cdot d\vec r=0
         \label{ce23}  
      \end{align} 
     
     
     \end{document}
```

Comment: There are no `\gather`, `\gathered`, or `\align` environments. There are environments called `gather`, `gathered`, and `align`. Using backslashes in front of environments will only lead to confusion and bad syntax (such as `\align...\endalign`, which technically works, but is bad practice).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `gather` instead of `gathered`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}  

\begin{gather}
    \Delta U_{ab}+\Delta U_{ba}=0 \nonumber\\
    \int_{\vec r_a}^{\vec r_b}\vec F\cdot d\vec r +\int_{\vec r_b}^{\vec r_a}\vec F\cdot d\vec r=0
    \label{ce23}
\end{gather}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ironically I did write the correct environment in the title

Answer (score 4):

It's better to use `gathered`, if possible, so TeX is able to use short vertical skips in case the line preceding the display is short. Compare the two otherwise identical displays: the space surrounding the second one is too wide.

The key is `\begin{gathered}[b]`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
 
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{equation}\label{ce23}
\begin{gathered}[b]
  \Delta U_{ab}+\Delta U_{ba}=0 \\
  \int_{\vec{r}_a}^{\vec{r}_b}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}
  +\int_{\vec{r}_b}^{\vec{r}_a}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}=0
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{gather}
  \Delta U_{ab}+\Delta U_{ba}=0 \notag \\
  \int_{\vec{r}_a}^{\vec{r}_b}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r} 
  +\int_{\vec{r}_b}^{\vec{r}_a}\vec{F}\cdot d\vec{r}=0
  \label{ce23bad}
\end{gather}
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I changed all `\vec r` and similar into the better `\vec{r}`, not more difficult to type and definitely clearer.

Comment: +1 for "I changed all `\vec r` and similar into the better `\vec{r}`".